# How to list all tables contaning a certain column in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I have 81 tables in AWS Athena, and now we need to change one column name. In order to do that, I should know the tables which has that particular column and checking 81 tables manually is a huge task. Is there any other way to list all tables having a particular column? maybe a query or some other trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query metadata from the AWS Glue Data Catalog to query tables. This assumes that your Amazon Athena system has been configured to use the AWS Glue Catalog.

From [Querying AWS Glue Data Catalog - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-glue-catalog.html):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  column_name='sid'
```

Comment: This should work in ideal world, but I am facing some metadata invalid issues